# What is the minimum Number of closed balls covering a boundary as radius $r\to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

Here is the problem: Given compact set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$, cover $\partial A$ by closed balls $\{B_{i,\varepsilon}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ , with minimum overlap. Can we express n
as a factor of $\varepsilon$ and properties of A eg. $diam(A)$ i.e. $n=f(x,p(A))$?

To ensure coverage, more balls would have to be added for smaller $\varepsilon$.

Corollary: this will give us the total Newtonian capacity of the balls covering the boundary for fixed $\varepsilon$. And that is what I am looking for.

So if the boundary is a line of length L, we get $n=\frac{L}{2\varepsilon}$. So an estimate for higher dimensions is $n=\frac{vol(\partial A)}{vol(B(\varepsilon))}$ with $dim(\partial A)=dim (B(\varepsilon))$. I am looking for a formula of fixed $\varepsilon$ not it's limit to zero.

thanks

Comment: The scaling of this number with $\varepsilon$ depends on the fractal dimension of the boundary; in particular, its Hausdorff dimension (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension).

Comment: @mjqxxxx Rather, the [Minkowski dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension) since the balls are of the same size. Hausdorff allows variable size of sets in a covering.

Answer (score 2):

The asymptotic behavior of $n(\epsilon)$ can be somewhat complicated. It is described by means upper Minkowski / box dimension
$$\overline{\dim}_M (\partial A)=\limsup_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\log n(\epsilon)}{\log(1/\epsilon)}$$ 
and its lower counterpart 
$$\underline{\dim}_M (\partial A)=\limsup_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\log n(\epsilon)}{\log(1/\epsilon)}$$ 
Unless $\partial A$ has intricate fractal structure that varies with scale (e.g., Cantor-type set where we  sometimes remove middle $1/3$ and sometimes middle $1/4$), both of these dimensions coincide with the better-known Hausdorff dimension $\dim_H$. In general  $$\dim_H \le \underline{\dim}_M \le \overline{\dim}_M$$
where both inequalities may be strict.

I do not know what you mean by "total Newtonian capacity of the boundary for fixed $\epsilon$." The Riesz capacities are   related to the Hausdorff dimension: see the statement in [formula (2.8) here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0406444.pdf) and for the proof (and additional results), see  Mattila's *Geometry of Sets and Measures*.

> Can we express $n$ as a factor of $\varepsilon$ and properties of $A$

If $\partial A$ is a rectifiable surface with area $S$, then $n(\epsilon)$ is asymptotic to $ c S \epsilon^{1-n}$ where $c$ is an absolute constant that depends only on dimension. This quantity is also related to the volume of $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the set. For details, see   the aforementioned book by Mattila.